# fastboot oem unlock: hangs with `...'

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, linux, bootloader, fastboot

First of all, I am a newbie to Android. I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 to run all the commads.

I am trying to unlock the bootloader of my Lenovo A536 (stock Android 4.4.2 aka KitKat). Here is what I am trying to do:

`$ adb devices              # lists the devices, apparently working
 List of devices attached 
 0123456789ABCDEF   device`

`$ adb reboot bootloader    # no terminal output; phone enters fastboot
                              (there is written '=> FASTBOOT mode...' in the
                              bottom-left corner`

`$ fastboot oem unlock      # and here it stops without exiting; I have to force quit
 ...                          the fastboot by holding the phone power button for over
                              10s and then the command in terminal ends`'

Before doing this I checked the USB debugging in the Developer’s menu.

**Update #1**
`lsusb` output (part of it) while the phone is connected to pc and booted in fastboot:

`$ lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 064: ID 0bb4:0c01 HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo`

**Update #2**
I found out that after installing a USB VCOM Driver on a Windows machine I was able to flash TWRP 2.7.1. I think Linux somehow does not recognise my phone.

Here is the [link](http://www.androidrookies.com/2014/12/lenovo-a536-how-to-installing-custom.html) with tutorial to flash TWRP 2.7.1 using Windows. Note that before running SP Flash Tool, you must connect phone *without* battery to the computer, and after selecting the scatter file, you must insert battery into phone, otherwise SP Flash Tool would not flash anything.

Comment: Does `lsusb` show the device connected while it's in fastboot mode?  Do you have the appropriate entries in `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`?  You might also have better luck running the command as the superuser.

Comment: @MatthewRead – I have just appended the `lsusb` output to the question. And I have not such file as `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` – should I create one? what should I contain? And running the command as superuser has same results.

Comment: Step 3: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

Comment: I just created the file with `sudo sh -exec "echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" && sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` (using `17ef` for the phone is a Lenovo), but still it hangs with the elipsis …

Comment: I tried even `sudo sh -exec "echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb|usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev, OWNER="ts", SYMLINK+="android_adb"\nSUBSYSTEM=="usb|usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev, OWNER="ts", SYMLINK+="android_fastboot"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules" && sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules && udevadm control --reload-rules`, and then `adb reboot bootloader && fastboot oem unlock`, but the result is still the same.

Comment: Alright, I think we can probably rule out your OS/tools being the issue (although it wouldn't hurt to try Windows if you are able).  I can't find very much information on this device.  Are you sure the bootloader is locked / have you tried flashing a recovery image?

Comment: I tried to flash TWRP prior to unlocking the bootloader, but it would not let me do it (I just cannot remember the error). And yes, it is difficult to find *any* valuable information on this device about unlocking, rooting, and flashing :). I will try the m$ window$, but wanted to do it  without it—well, it should be easier to do it on Linux machine for android is basically a heavily modified Linux, but I do not know how.

Comment: I have the same problem. The symptoms show a Linux problem, what is really sad.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation on 'android' to answer the question, but see this answer I posted to XDA Forums: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/all-fastboot-commands-hang-except-fastboot-devices-bad-hardware.4184331/

TLDR this works:  /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/fastboot oem get_unlock_data